# bezier path select same color

Tags: ios, iphone, image, uibezierpath

In my application I have created 3D effect image for example suppose user have selected all the flower using bezier path than after clicking on done button all the image except flowers will become blur. I have done this successfully. Now I want to enhance this functionality. What I need is that when user select flower than only flower should be selectable not green color.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Edit:

Example of such application is https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/tadaa-hd-pro-camera/id410005685?mt=8 I just need some help to start this. in this application how they are selecting object?

Please suggest me some SDK or toll to start.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no direct answer for it. you have to go step by step